# \newpage or \clearpage doesn't work

Tags: macros

For exmaple, The fist page is filled with text. I insert a chart  after the text and add some text after it, Once I use `\newpage` or `\clearpage`, the problems below will take place:

1. `\newpage`: This command isn't effective
2. `\clearpage`: This command can break the page, but the chart is put in the center of the next page and the addings are put in the other page

I just want the chart putting at the top of the page. What should I do?

the example of the code:

```
% !TEX program=pdflatex 
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[fontsize=24.88pt]{fontsize}
\begin{document}
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE

    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    There are some nonsenses below.Please IGNORE
    
    \begin{table}[t!]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            a & b & c & d\\
            \hline
            1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
            \hline
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}

    \clearpage
    
    hahahaha
\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you use a table environment? That is a float with special placement rules see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388

Comment: Basically [floats - Force figure placement in text - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)